# Yahoo Robot by PHP

Tags: php, yahoo

I'm trying to develop yahoo messenger robot by php,I develop e base part of it,now I can receive pm,add request,new status and I can answer to them.

I wanna it work for ever , so I use

```
while(1){
recive();
answer();
}
```

in each request to recive e message,it will open url by curl and get json data.

each pm take 1s to send I think,I check it when my server was in Germany,now how can I speed up it?
and is my algorithm true?is it true way to do it?or yahoo will filter me?
(My Yahoo Robot is not for spam,it will answer customer questions)

Comment: Waaay too broad a question. Narrow it down to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/knorrium/messenger-sdk-php), the `robot.php` file starts up a new Messenger bot. The `config` folder has a small sample of configuration. The `Client.php` file has some logic about the interaction.

Please note that the project is largely undocumented, but we've been using it to automate acceptance tests on Yahoo! Messenger based products very well.